# Scroll Bar not working on MFC application built in VS2010

Tags: screen-resolution

One of our client was facing an issue in screeen resolution and we tested with his other laptops then working fine. But we don't know why it was not working in his laptop. Please find below details on this issue.

Actual Screenshot
[image: Actual screen]

Expected Screenshot
[image: Expected screen]

Here, I thought there is no issue from V-scroll bar. I got surprise at Why application get shrink even though scrollbar is supported till the end. We have received this issue from one of our end user(Win 7) and we have tested in all our machines(Win 7), but it was not reproducible at all. We need the answers for the following things.

•In which case this issue may occur?
•How to reproduce the same issue in our machines?(Win 7)
•We suspect, some system configuration may not support at the end user side. If yes, please tell what are those configurations? (For ex: Screen resolution)
•We also suspect, display driver. Let me know, what are the possibilities and what are the things we need to finalize with that person on this issue?